# How to Update Value In Firebase using Python

Tags: python, html, pyrebase

So, I was trying to update a certain node of my firebase realtime database, but I not aware of the steps I need to follow to accomplish the task.
here is my database:

[image: Database screenshot]

```
<tr>                                       
    {%for k,v in dataDb.items():%}
    {%for key,value in v.items():%}
    <td>{{value}}</td>
    
    {%endfor%}
    <td><a class="a" href="btnDelete">Update</a></td>
    <td><a class="a" href="btnDelete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Here I'am just tryin to display all the values, But how can i edit a single node?

Answer (score 0):

According to Pyrebase documentation, you can use [`update()` method](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#update) to update data for an existing entry. So it would look something like this:

`db.child("client").child("MGPDMDfQy...").update({"b": "888-888-8888"})`

Comment: yeah, I know but how would I know which node is being clicked?

Comment: @gursimar_hehar Are you also using Flask or Django? So your question is actually about how to handle the HTML form?

Comment: So how would you append another value, like 'i : something new" under the existing id